# SQL table join to find matching data

Tags: sql-server

We are in the healthcare business and we have a SQL database where we store the indications (how much care should the client receive in minutes) and the appointments (how much care have we delivered to the client in minutes).

**The query i wrote is as follow:**

```
SELECT

CF.ClientNr,
C.Name,
F.Description AS Function,
CF.Time AS Indication,
SUM(P.Minutes) As Production,
C.Insurance,
V.Name AS Team

FROM ClientFunctie AS CF

INNER JOIN Client AS C ON C.ClientNr=CF.ClientNr
INNER JOIN HoofdaanbiederFunctie AS H ON CF.HoofdaanbiederFunctieNr=H.HoofdaanbiederFunctieNr
INNER JOIN Functie AS F ON H.FunctieNr=F.FunctieNr

LEFT JOIN Planning AS P ON CF.ClientFunctieNr=P.ClientFunctieNr
LEFT JOIN DeclaratieAfhandeling AS D ON P.DeclaratieAfhandelingNr=D.DeclaratieAfhandelingNr
LEFT JOIN Vestiging AS V ON P.VestigingNr=V.VestigingNr

WHERE 

D.StatusNr = 2 AND
CF.Einddatum > '2018-01-01' /*startdatum*/ AND
CF.Startdatum < '2018-01-28' /*einddatum*/ AND
CF.IsAkkoord = 1 AND
F.Omschrijving LIKE '%mwa%' AND
F.Omschrijving LIKE '%hv%'

GROUP BY

CF.ClientNr,
C.Name,
F.Description AS Function,
CF.Time AS Indication,
C.Insurance,
V.Name AS Team
```

My goal is to know how many minutes per indications have been delivered and how many indications have received 0 minutes.

Right now i only see the indications in my results with minutes but i also want to see which indications have 0 minutes. I tried to play with the left/right join but im right now out of options. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: For the first, you can't use keyword "Function" in select as alias like in your example -> "F.Description AS Function". You will get an error like below "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Function"

Comment: Either your join or where clause is limiting the results to only those patients that have received care. We don't know the table relations and thus can't solve this without sample data and expected out put. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

It is  bit hard without table structure but here how I usually go.

I think I would extract the calculations in a subquery and edit the main query in consequence, something like that:

```
SELECT CF.ClientNr,
C.Name,
F.Description AS Function,
CF.Time AS Indication,
WL-Production As Production,
C.Insurance,
V.Name AS Team

FROM [...]
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(P.Minutes) As Production, CF.ClientNr as ClientNr 

FROM ClientFunctie AS CF
INNER JOIN Planning AS P ON CF.ClientFunctieNr = P.ClientFunctieNr
INNER JOIN DeclaratieAfhandeling AS D ON P.DeclaratieAfhandelingNr = D.DeclaratieAfhandelingNr

WHERE D.StatusNr = 2
GROUP BY CF.ClientNr) AS WL ON CF.ClientFunctieNr = WL.ClientNr
```

(I do not have a SqlServer to test it out hopefully that will help)

You could use the same approach for counting the 0 minutes indications.

Also looking at your query it seems like you also need the name of the need Team who did the job, your queries might need some adjustments if you need the the total of time no matter which Team did the job.